# Android Marker Description, another view Details HELP :(

Tags: android, maps

In the end of this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?x-yt-ts=1421782837&x-yt-cl=84359240&v=l3bw8Senjmg#t=208

he says you can add an detail for the marker that will show another view with the details... how can I implemente this? Im looking for this but I only find old tutorials that doesn't work with me. My map is already populate, info window show great

Comment: he means some kind of Activity or Dialog(Fragment)...

Comment: But how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean how to do something when the info window is clicked:

```
GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();

map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
            // Do whatever you want here
        }
);
```

This assumes you're using the support library with a map fragment having the id "map".  Adjust accordingly to suit your needs.